# Call to undefined method PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance()

Tags: ubuntu, phpunit, pear

I've got a fresh copy of PHPUnit installed on my system (Ubuntu 11), but whenever I type `phpunit` in the console I get the following error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance() in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 39`

I have PHPUnit's code coverage installed, as far as I know:

`>sudo pear install phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage`

`phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.1.1`

`install failed`

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: What versions of PHPUnit is installed? `pear info phpunit/PHPUnit` It seems that the `phpunit` executable script was not updated to 3.6.x.

Comment: `Release Date          2012-01-27 10:49:19
Release Version       3.6.10 (stable)`

Comment: As of the end of 2014 you cannot install phpunit via pear at all anymore.

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The executable script that loads PHPUnit must not have been updated when going to 3.6.x. Reinstall it.

```
sudo pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit
sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

If this doesn't work, [make sure PEAR itself is up-to-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053047/cant-run-phpunit-after-upgrade-from-3-5-14-to-3-6-10-closed-not-an-issue).

Comment: Can you write here how to make PEAR up-to-date? The link does not exits now.

Answer (score 118):

Ubuntu 11.10 has had an issue for a while that hasn't been fixed. This is the only thing that will get phpunit to work with pear. (Outside of using pear you can look up a way to do it without pear. There is an article online about that but I wouldn't want that kind of burden to do it manually). This is the only thing that worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove phpunit

sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de

sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com

sudo pear channel-discover components.ez.no

sudo pear update-channels

sudo pear upgrade-all

sudo pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit

sudo pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Comment: It also worked for my (old) 12.04 insall (10.04 -> 11.04 -> 11.10 -> 12.04)

Comment: Supergreen, saved me a lot of time! Works like a charm.

Comment: If you are troubleshooting from another install, maybe you get a bash: not found message. Just open another tab or terminal to fix it.

Comment: I found another solution that didn't have that last line (`sudo pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit`). By running that last line, finally, it instantly worked.

Answer (score 23):

For some, Anthony's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9407628/295264) will not work fully because of the `Unknown remote channel: pear.symfony.com` or `phpunit/PHPUnit requires package "channel://pear.symfony.com/Yaml"`.

SO here is the upgraded solution that solves this:

```
sudo apt-get remove phpunit

sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de

sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com

sudo pear channel-discover components.ez.no

sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com

sudo pear update-channels

sudo pear upgrade-all

sudo pear install pear.symfony.com/Yaml

sudo pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit

sudo pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Comment: After a LOT of fishing around to get phpUnit working on my Ubuntu 12.04 VM, this solution worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed Ubuntu 12.04 - don't see what everyone was complaining about, that was *so* simples! </sarcasm>

Answer (score 1):

The method `getInstance()` seems to have been dropped from the class.
https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/blob/master/PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php#L78

Use the constructor instead if you come across this error. However, this is not applicable to the opening post as the command came from PHPUnit itself.

Answer (score 1):

it works for me. at the beginning, I didn't use --force for the last command, I got a fatal error that "Call to undefined method PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance". Then I used --force, which resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

While i had the same problem and managed to solve it using setting correct environment variables.

You can get to the solve here
http://rkrants.blogspot.in/2013/01/installing-phpunitpear-in-ubuntu-1210.html

In short I had to re-install PHPUnit using pear after setting the variables correct.

I used a Ubuntu 12.10 installation and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem, managed to solve it using composer

Try these steps -

First uninstall phpunit

```
sudo apt-get remove phpunit
```

Install composer - http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installation

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Install phpunit - http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/installation.html

For a system-wide installation via Composer, you can run:

```
$ composer global require 'phpunit/phpunit=3.7.*'
```

You will also have to make sure that you have ~/.composer/vendor/bin/ in your path.