# PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance() Error running phpunit

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit, code-coverage

I have installed phpunit in my ubuntu 11.10 having php version 5.2.14.

But when I run my test module it is throwing error,

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance() in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 64
```

I followed the steps mention in this stack question but still no luck.

[Call to undefined method PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186000/call-to-undefined-method-php-codecoverage-filtergetinstance)

Comment: Please do not add `random` code `formatting` to your question.  It makes it very hard to read.

Comment: @Charles -I have check your edit & will take care of it from next time. Thanks !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following steps solved my problem.

```
sudo apt-get remove phpunit

sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de

sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com

sudo pear channel-discover components.ez.no

sudo pear update-channels

sudo pear upgrade-all

sudo pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit

sudo pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Answer (score 1):

One workaround - granted, not really a solution - is to bypass PEAR install and use a local copy via [Composer install](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).

Create a file in project root called `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit" : "3.7.*"
    }
}
```

Of course, modify the phpunit version to "3.6.*" or similar, if you have such a requirement.

At project root:

```bsh
# Install composer
$ curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

# Tell composer to install the dependencies identified in composer.json
$ php composer.phar install

# Now you can invoke the *local* copy of phpunit
$ ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit --version
```

For simplicity, you can can create a symlink to the phpunit executable. Assuming you want the symlink in a directory called `tests`:

```bsh
$ ln -s ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit ./tests/phpunit
```

Then you can invoke as (from project root):

```bsh
$ cd tests
$ ./phpunit --version
```

Even easier, you can direct Composer to handling the symlinking for you. Add this to your `composer.json`:

```
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "tests"
}
```

Then, as before, you can invoke as (from project root):

```bsh
$ cd tests
$ ./phpunit --version
```

Actually, what I usually do is have a project-level directory called `scripts` and point my composer `bin-dir` there. Then I manually create a symlink in `tests` pointing to `scripts/phpunit`. But this last step is probably more personal taste than any kind of requirement.

Maybe a long way to go just to beat PEAR issues, but I find Composer-based install works pretty reliably for me.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I got phpunit installed now from above stack overflow question ref. but now I am getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /usr/share/php/File/Iterator/Autoload.php on line 45
` error when I run phpunit command.

Comment: A syntax error like that in an downloaded component like PHPUnit sounds like an incomplete download. I'd remove and re-install.

Comment: Aaah, I notice you are on PHP 5.2.14. PHPUnit 3.7 requires PHP >= 5.3.3, while PHPUnit 3.6 only requires PHP >= 5.2.7. Unless you have a need to be at PHP 5.2, I'd recommend a boost to 5.3.

Comment: Yeah I googled & get to know it (
phpunit) only requires PHP >= 5.2.7, but I can't upgrade it.Still searching for some other solution :( ..Thanks for your great help

Comment: You can still use the composer-based install. Just specify `3.6.*` for the phpunit version in `composer.json`.

Answer (score 0):

my platform Symfony 1.4 did not have installed the latest version of the plugin that is compatible with latest phpunit version. So updating to latest version of https://github.com/JWT-OSS/sfJwtPhpUnitPlugin/ worked for me.