# PHPUnit Cannot redeclare class File_Iterator_Factory error in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-4

I'm developed the application using Laravel 4 and install the PHPUnit using Composer. But when I run the "phpunit" command in the console I'm getting following error.

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class File_Iterator_Factory in G:\xampp\htdocs\airasia-github\vendor\p
hpunit\php-file-iterator\File\Iterator\Factory.php on line 57
```

This used in the composer.json

```
"require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
    }
```

Comment: I got it fixed by following below links.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186000/call-to-undefined-method-php-codecoverage-filtergetinstance
http://zurmo.org/forums/index.php?/topic/42-php-unit-on-window7-with-xampp/

Comment: no :-( sorry for that.