# Call to undefined method PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance() in Netbeans 7.4

Tags: php, phpunit, pear

I am new to PHPUnit.
I have installed PHPUnit using PEAR
I am using PHP 5.4.7

When I give command **phpunit --bootstrap src/autoload.php tests/MoneyTest** I got the below error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance() in D:\xampp\php\phpunit on line 39

If I run the same code with Netbeans 7.4, the same error occurs.

Please provide your suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186000/call-to-undefined-method-php-codecoverage-filtergetinstance

Comment: Hi Royal, Thanks, but again it shows No releases available for package "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit"

Comment: Hi Royal, Thank you. I tried with composer. It throws an exception "You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https"