# PHPUnit doesn't allow me to include files

Tags: phpunit

PHPUnit is giving me an error message whenever I try to include a file. For example the follwing code gives me the error:

```
<?php

include_once "PHPUnit/Autoload.php";
require_once "controller/ProductController.php";

class SecurityTests extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testSmth() {
        $this->assertTrue(1==1);
    }
}
```

?>

But if I remove the fourth line (`require_once "controller/ProductController.php";`), it runs fine.

The error I get is:

```
Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Framework/Error.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\pear\PHPUnit\Util\ErrorHandler.php on line 48
```

**EDIT:**
My include_path in the php.ini file is:

```
include_path = ".;E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\pear\;E:\wamp\www\renting\"
```

What is strange:

```
<?php
echo get_include_path(); **// Will echo .;E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\pear\;E:\wamp\www\renting\** 
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
require_once 'controller/AccountController.php';
echo get_include_path(); **// Will echo E:/wamp/www/renting/**
```

And also:

```
<?php

require_once 'controller/AccountController.php';
echo get_include_path(); **// Will echo E:/wamp/www/renting/**
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';

echo get_include_path(); **// Will not even echo.**
```

This is very strange to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your directory structure look like and from where are you running the test?

Comment: I am using PhpStorm for running the tests, but if I run it from the test folder with command line, I get the same results.

Comment: If I remove the included file, I don't get any sort of error, the tests run okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it took me days to figure this one out. I hope nobody will ever go through what I went.

I had in my php.ini:

```
include_path = ".;E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\pear\;E:\wamp\www\renting\"
```

But because I used to not use multiple php include paths in my ini file, I had used

```
set_include_path("E:/wamp/www/renting/");
```

in some of the files, even if they weren't the ones that I was trying to include.

Anyway, it might sound silly and confusing, but **if you find yourself in a situation where PHPUnit does not load properly for some reason, think of the possibility of your code changing the include path somehow.**

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, PHPUnit could not locate files in parent directories. It only
located files being children to the current directory of the class importing them, e,g.

file structure:

```
var/
    www/
        /api
            index.php
            conf.php
        /config
           dbconfig.php
```

## index.php

```
require_once 'conf.php'; #works fine
require_once '../config/dbconfig.php; #ERROR
```

PHPUnit has problems finding the relative path when trying to go to parent folders. 
After reading [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1882059/9348902) The solution was to insert `dirname(dirname(__FILE__))`, `dirname(__FILE__)` which returns the path of the current directory, by applying `dirname` to the path, it returns the parent path.

## index.php

```
require_once 'conf.php'; #works fine
require_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '../config/dbconfig.php'; #works fine.
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a know issue.

Verify your PHUnit installed below packeges:

> pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
>    pear channel-discover
>   components.ez.no
>   pear install phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage

try **sudo** if you don't have permissions.

Some links which helps you :

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phpunit/+bug/701544

[fatal error 'File/Iterator/Autoload.php' not found when running phpunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700642/fatal-error-file-iterator-autoload-php-not-found-when-running-phpunit)

[phpunit require_once() error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528717/phpunit-require-once-error)

Comment: Well, it seems that my files aren't actually missing and there is nothing for me to download. The problem is that it doesn't manage to include the files that it needs even though they are there. I do not get it.