# How to include file in phpunit test?

Tags: php, testing, include, phpunit, phpstorm

I'm having some trouble including a file in a phpunit test. For example: when I execute the following code in PhpStorm I get the expected output.

Code:

```
class NifvalidationTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function test_apiRequest()
    {
        $result = 1+1;
        $this->assertEquals(2, $result);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Testing started at 16:58 ...
PHPUnit 5.2.12 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.



Time: 120 ms, Memory: 11.50Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But when I need to access a method from another class using the include, I dont get the expected output. Just as an example, when I execute the following code:

```
class NifvalidationTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function test_apiRequest()
    {
        include('/../nifvalidation.php');
        $result = 1+1;
        $this->assertEquals(2, $result);
    }
}
```

I get this instead of the expected output:

```
Testing started at 17:05 ...
PHPUnit 5.2.12 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any ideas on why the include is breaking the test?

Note 1: In the above example I dont need to include the file, but I need in another tests.

Note 2: The path to the file 'nifvalidation.php' is correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193816/phpunit-doesnt-allow-me-to-include-files

Comment: Thank you for the answer @FelippeDuarte, but Im having some trouble understanding the best answer in that question.

Comment: Your problem seems to be something with your nifvalidation.php file. Could you show the code for us?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte you're right. The problem is with my nifvalidation.php file, since I tested with a different file and there is no problem. My nifvalidation.php has a class that extends a prestashop class:
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class Nifvalidation extends Module
{
//...
}

The problem is with the if condition before the class definition. But if i dont have that condition the class 'Module' is not found.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`bootstrap` flag](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html) when invoking the tests from the command line to include any files, define constants, and load all your variables, classes, etc.

> ```
> --bootstrap <file>        A "bootstrap" PHP file that is run before the tests.
> ```

For example, create an `autoload.php` which defines the constants and includes your files, then you can invoke it from the command line as such:

```
phpunit --bootstrap autoload.php testsFolder/NifvalidationTest
```

For a more automated approach, you can also [create a phpunit.xml file](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html#organizing-tests.xml-configuration) which contains the bootstrap information:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="autoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Nifvalidation Test Suite">
            <directory>./testsFolder</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

In this specific case, based on your comments about the contents of `nifvalidation.php` the script exits because `PS_VERSION` is not defined. If you're doing isolated unit tests that simply require one dummy constant defined, then you can define that to be present in your test environment. Then you can simply bootstrap your `nifvalidation.php` file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="../nifvalidation.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Nifvalidation Test Suite">
            <directory>./testsFolder</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <php>
        <const name="PS_VERSION" value="whatever you need here"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 7):

I think your include path is wrong. 
Your structure may be somewhat like this 
ParentDir 
   -> nifvalidation.php 
   -> testsFolder
     -> NifvalidationTest.php

instead of

```
include('/../nifvalidation.php')
```

use

```
include(dirname(__FILE__)."/../nifvalidation.php");
```

Comment: Yes, the structure is like that. I tried using the include as you suggested but unfortunately doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Use `require()` or `require_once()` instead of using `include()`