# How to fix error when installing pear in order to install phpunit?

Tags: php, phpunit

I am not quite sure if the question belongs to this forum, so if not and you are about to close this question, please make a suggestion where else to ask this question.

Basically, I need to install `phpunit` on Ubuntu 12.04. By doing so with the packet manager I get an error when running `phpunit`:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 38
```

for which there are [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528717/phpunit-require-once-error), i.e. to install `phpunit` with `pear`.

Following the [pear install instructions](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php) I download and run `go-pear.phar`, which itself produces an error

```
PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 0 in phar:///home/alexander/opt/src/go-pear.phar/Console/Getopt.php on line 145
```

Any suggestions how to proceed from here? I also ONLY need `phpunit`, so `pear` will be used just for this case once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation of `phpunit` really seems to be extremly complicated and circumstantial, but here is the solution:

- As for Ubuntu 12.04 `pear` should be already installed
- However, the latest version of `pear` should be used
- And `phpunit` need to be removed before it is reinstalled

The whole procedure and each step is described [on symfony-world](http://symfony-world.blogspot.ch/2012/10/phpunit-install-on-ubuntu-problem-fix.html), one might need the additional step shown in the given comment. Here is a copy-and-paste of the complete procedure for Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get remove phpunit
sudo apt-get upgrade pear
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
sudo pear channel-discover components.ez.no
sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
sudo pear update-channels
sudo pear upgrade-all
sudo pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need only phpunit, use [composer](http://getcomposer.org/).. For example composer.json may look like:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the command line statement to use? Do I have to install composer?

Comment: yes, you need to install composer and run `composer install` or `composer update` which will use this composer.json file as dependency description (the names will be resolved to relevant URLs through packagist server)

Comment: Well, I tried the chain, but `phpunit` gives the exact error as before.

Comment: AFAIK it does not install phpunit to global /usr/bin dir, you probably still run PEAR installation. Look for `vendor/bin/phpunit` and try running that